# Parsing and Solving a Formula in Java SE 8

Tags: java, parsing, token, formula, equation

### Disclaimer: Not Homework

I've written very basic calculator parsers in Java using tokenizers, but I have recently started writing a problem to help me understand chemistry. As I began writing more and more formulas, it became increasingly apparent that the complexity required to solve for each equation is almost more tedious than mastery of the equations themselves. Take the equation PV = nRT, how could I write a parser that would allow me to input all know variables and solve if it was solvable? I can do the logic behind solvability, but here are a few requirements:

- must be able to solve for any unknown variable.
- parsing should be capable for formulas of any size (ex: I want to implement more than one formula, such as π = MRT and formulas of increasing complexity, and only want to have to define them once.)

Once again this is purely for my enjoyment and to be used as a learning tool. Any help would be appreciated, as searching Google and StackOverflow for this problem have given me either vague or inapplicable answers.

Comment: What is the long form of `PV = nRT`? Is it `PV = nRT` or is it `PV = n * RT` or is it `PV = n * R * T`? There would need to be rules for your variables within an equation.

Comment: This (symbolic algebra) is a very complex problem that has provided fertile ground for many a PhD thesis.  The industry standards are Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha (although they also do a lot more).  Both these products represent hundreds of person-years of work, and we cannot possibly explain how to do this as a StackOverflow answer.  Here's a good starting point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra

Comment: I apologize if my question is too broad. I don’t want anything fancy just a solution like Juan’s. Also P*V = n *R*T. I can post some production style code if anything but I feel like having a mostly empty method is distracting and detracts from the overall quality of possible answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have posted no code I will speak my thoughts.

I used to have an [hp48G](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP48) calculator which had a library with many formulas covering different areas.

Instead of parsing a single line, you had to choose through menus which was the formula to apply, then the calculator would ask for each parameter separately, and apply it to the formula to provide the result.

If you follow this approach, and helped with java's interfaces I think you can do something like you are asking.

Comment: This is definitely helpful. Thank you for the valuable input I’ll check it out tonight.